# Word, Paste Formatted Text without Importing/Changing Styles

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, styles, templates

At work we recently changed our Word Templates and I am creating a new document that has a lot of boilerplate text in it. I am good with styles and am anal about how they show up in the Style Gallery.

Anyways any time I copy text or tables over from a previous document, even though I am selecting "Use Destination Theme" it will still import any styles that don't have the exact same name as a style in the new document AND it changes the priority numbering of the styles that are already in the document. Changing the priority numbers mess up how the styles show up in the Style Galley.

Is there a way to copy in formatted text, without importing unknown Styles and without messing with the priority of the existing Styles?

I am using Word 2013, I don't recall having this issue in 2010.

Edit: I know about pasting plain text, but when pasting large amounts of formatted text, including many tables that is a pretty annoying way of doing things. I'd like Word is uses the existing Styles, without importing or modifying any.

Comment: Check in word Options Advanced, cut copy and paste see the options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also use styles every day at work and have found that when pasting text into a styled doc, and want to retain the formatting without disturbing the style gallery, I don't just paste using one of the three Paste options. I select Paste in the Home tab on the left, Paste Special, then Formatted Text (RTF). This pastes in the text with its original formatting without interfering with anything. I then just have to style it all using the heading and body test styles, because although it will LOOK styled, it won't be.
I hope this answers your question? It has solved many a problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this also.
Unfortunately *Paste As RTF* still brings in template styles!
So my solution is to

1. run WordPad from the start menu
2. paste into WordPad `(CTRL+V)`
3. Select All `(CTRL+A)`
4. Copy `(CTRL+C)`
5. Flip back to Word
6. Paste `(CTRL+V)`